# OLS estimation for Nonlinear model

Tags: self-study, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, convergence

> Consider the following model which may be nonlinear:
>
> $Y_{t} = f (X_{t}, \beta_{0}) + \mu_{t}, \hspace{0.2cm} t=1, ..., T$
>
> If we assume that:
>
> 1. $\mu_{t}$ i.i.d with mean = $0$ and variance $\sigma_{0}^{2} < \infty$
> 2. The parameter space $B$ is nonempty and compact
> 3. $f (X_{t}, \beta)$ is non random for all $\beta \in B$
> 4. $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}[f (X_{t}, \beta_{0})-f (X_{t}, \beta)]^2$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $A(\beta)$, which attains its minimum only in $\beta = \beta_{0}$
>
> Let $\hat{\beta_{T}}$ be the OLS estimation for $\beta_{0}$.
>
> **Does $\hat{\beta_{T}}$ converges in probability to $\beta_{0}$ when $T\rightarrow \infty$?**

I'm trying to solve this problem because our professor stated it as a "recommended excercise". I've tried consulting Amemiya's "Advanced Econometrics" book and other references to get an idea but I'm still stuck on the problem. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks @gung I'm new at this platform so I didn't know about self-study tag. So far, what I don't understand is why does the problem states that $\beta_{T}$ is the OLS estimator for a model which may be nonlinear. Let say the model is, in fact, nonlinear. Can we estimate its parameter vector by the standard OLS formula $\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$?. Will it be well defined?

Comment: have you tried finding a counterexample?

Comment: @ChristophHanck No I haven´t. Do you mean a counterexample for the main problem? Or for the question I asked in my previous comment?

Comment: For the main problem. For example, some discrete choice model might fit your assumptions, for whose parameters OLS is generally not consistent.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophHanck I'll give it a try. I'll come back and post if I get to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

OLS is generally consistent for the *linear projection coefficients* $\beta^\star$, see e.g. any somewhat advanced econometrics textbook like Hayashi's. In the case of a simple regression without constant (for simplicity),
$$
\beta^\star=\frac{E(X\cdot Y)}{E(X^2)}
$$
Let us consider the case where $P(X_i=-1)=P(X_i=1)=0.5$ and $Y_i=\exp(X_i\beta)+u_i$, $u_i$ independent of $X_i$. Without having checked carefully, this example should fit your set of assumptions. Then,
$$
E(X\cdot Y)=E(X\exp(X\beta))=-0.5\exp(-\beta)+0.5\exp(\beta)
$$
and $E(X^2)=1$. So for $\beta=1$, OLS is consistent for $0.5[\exp(\beta)-\exp(-\beta)]\approx1.18$, not 1.

Here is an illustration for a sample size of $n=500$ and 10,000 replications to simulate the resulting distribution, which we see centers around 1.18, not 1.

[image]

```
library(MASS)
reps <- 10000
olse <- rep(NA,reps)

n <- 500
beta <- 1
plimols <- (exp(beta) - exp(-beta))/2

for (i in 1:reps) {
  X <- 2*(runif(n)>.5)-1
  u <- rnorm(n,sd=.1)
  y <- exp(beta*X) + u
  olse[i] <- lm(y~X-1)$coefficients  
}
truehist(olse,col="salmon")
abline(v=plimols,col="gold",lwd=3)
abline(v=beta,col="purple",lwd=3)
mean(olse)
```

Comment: Indeed, but OP says that "let $\hat{\beta_{T}}$ be the *O*LS estimation" - my understanding was that he wants to know what happens if you regress, by OLS, $Y$ on $X$ even though the true relationship is *non*linear. I may have misunderstood his question, of course - maybe @MarcusFermat can clarify?

Comment: Hm, in that case I would have misunderstood - I suggest I wait to withdraw the answer until this gets confirmed, and then the post should be edited replacing OLS with NLS (see his first comment under the original question, though!).

Comment: Yes, that does clearly support your interpretation - and indicates the source of the ambiguity is not the OP but the author of the question. Perhaps more information about the source (such as a complete reference, if it's from a book) would be useful, and your answer does partly respond to the issue in the comment. I'll delete my earlier comments.